# SQL Server: How can I copy data from one table to another table without the characters 'e+' being added to the results

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am copying data from a table created by an Excel spreadsheet import.

Here is what I am doing to move the data from the import table to the actual table:

```
INSERT INTO TableName ([Column1], [Column2])
SELECT [Column1], [Column2] FROM [Sheet1$]
```

After I execute this under column 1 I get records like:

`5.31752e+007` when the actual value of that record (from the table I am importing from) is `5046610163`

Any ideas?

Comment: What are the types of column 1 on each table?

Comment: Yep - You probably want `int` or `decimal` rather than float. Not sure how `5046610163` ends up as `5.31752e+007` though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't specify whether it was Column1 or Column2 that has the float data in it, but here's an example assuming Column1 is what you need.

```
INSERT INTO TableName ([Column1], [Column2])
SELECT CAST([Column1] AS decimal(38,2)), [Column2] FROM [Sheet1$]
```

I use the same code to convert to varchar without all that formatting quite often:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(100), CAST(@value as decimal(38,2)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO TableName ([Column1], [Column2])
    SELECT UPPER([Column1]), [Column2] 
    FROM [Sheet1$]
```

**EDIT**

OK -- then try to first open your excel sheet, create a 3rd column, and make it a formula (=UPPER(A1)), where A1 is actually whatever column you're having the trouble with.

Beyond that, if you search for "scientific notation" in Excel help, you'll get some limited advice there as well.

**EDIT 2**

Or try this in TSQL:

```
INSERT INTO TableName ([Column1], [Column2])
select LTRIM(str(cast([Column1] as real))), [Column2]
FROM [Sheet1$]
```

Comment: 5.31751E+007 <-- it just turns the lowercase e to an upper case e

Comment: Darn.  One more think you can try -- see my ammended answer above.

Comment: Is Excel exporting it as a string then?

Comment: @Martin -- that's what I suspect...  Because the actual value of the field is not stored in scientific notiation in excel afaik -- it's just displayed that way in the cell.

Comment: Whether it's coming from excel in scientific notation or not, casting it to decimal should fix. I believe you can even cast a varchar representation of scientific notation to decimal.

Comment: I think it was the method I used to import. I converted the file to a CSV then imported as opposed to importing directly from Excel and it worked. The column values were accurate. Thank you guys so much for your help!! Though it is still very very weird.